# How to display keyboard in iOS8

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield

Im trying to convert my iOS7 project to iOS8

When I built the app in iPhone 5s simulator for iOS8.0, I found the keyboard would no longer appear automatically when clicking a `UITextField` or `UITextView`...

Is there any one can tell me how to solve this?

thanks~

Comment: possibly a bug with the beta. This should still work as expected.

Comment: Go to Simulator->Hardware and change the keyboard simulation

Comment: oh, it works~ thank you for your reply! Sam~

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fix this, on simulator, open the Menu: Hardware - Keyboard - Toggle software menu (make sure it's checked)

Comment: Weird. On some simulators it is shown automatically and on some I have to toggle.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that was the reverse of the above.  When I built the app in simulator for iOS7.0 the keyboard not showing up.

The above answer solved the problem for IOS 7 builds as well.

Comment: Sorry.  I'm just trying to draw attention to the better answer.  Yours was the big hammer by advising people to make sure a default setting is turned off.  The more appropriate solution was already provided.

Comment: the toggle is greyed out (disabled) because you have the hardware keyboard disabled.  The option is only relevant if the hardware keyboard is enabled.