# Keyboard is not working proper in ios7 (Xcode 6)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, keyboard, uitextfield

I have recently installed Xcode 6 in OS X Mavericks.In iOS 8 my app is working fine.
But in iOS 7 sometime keyboard does not appear when i tap on textfield or textview.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some code or screenshot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this, on simulator, open the Menu: Hardware - Keyboard - Toggle software menu (make sure it's checked)

[link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752981/how-to-display-keyboard-in-ios8)

Comment: @ThuốcĐộc I couldn't mark it is as checked :(. Because it is says Toggle software keyboard. I don't know how you people getting checked.