# Keyboard not shown under iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uikeyboard

When focus on my app's textfields, none of them can call out the keyboard, I cannot enter any letter. But before iOS 8 is okay.

I tried to rotate the screen and found that the keyboard is shown out bounds of the screen, checked the view frame, it's 1024 * 768, seems correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keyboard is not working proper in ios7 (Xcode 6)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805689/keyboard-is-not-working-proper-in-ios7-xcode-6)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, find that it's simulator's issue, not iOS 8's bug.

#### Workaround:

> iOS Simulator > Hardware > Keyboard > Toggle Software Keyboard
>
> or just press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

Yeah, I've connected a hardware keyboard via bluetooth, but didn't notice this keyboard toggle function until now. Seems Xcode 6 will use my hardware keyboard by default.

Answer (score 3):

Open Simulator.

Go to Hardware.

Then select Keyboard.

Then choose iOS Users Same Layout As OS X

**Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> iOS Users Same Layout As OS X**

[image]

Comment: My "Connect Hardware Keyboard" is checked either, I guess it's just my hardware keyboard issue. Anyway, thx, maybe helpful to others :)

Comment: if "Connect Hardware Keyboard" is check then keyboard is not showing either "iOS uses Same Layout As OS X" is checked or not, no problem but u have to uncheck "Connect Hardware Keyboard"

Comment: Both "iOS Uses Same Layout As OS X" & "Connect Hardware Keyboard" are checked. And I notice pressing Cmd + K to toggle software keyboard seems very helpful. ;)

Comment: iOS Uses Same Layout As OS X has nothing to do with the software keyboard being visible or not.  If the hardware keyboard is not connected, the software keyboard will always be visible when typing.  If the hardware keyboard is disconnected, the software keyboard can be toggled while typing.